# CSS3 Pseudo-classes to realize a specific menu

Tags: css, separator

I have the following menu and ccs, but it will not run to get the Following menu?! The separator does not have the link from the text.

**TEXT 1 | TEXT 2 | TEXT 3**

```
ul.tabs > li.hasmore .font_menue::after {
  content: ' | ';
}

ul.tabs > li.hasmore .font_menue:last-child::after {
  content: '';
}


<div id="navigation">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="hasmore">
        <a href="text1.php"><span class="font_menue">TEXT 1</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="hasmore">
        <a href="text2.php"><span class="font_menue">TEXT 2</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="hasmore">
        <a href="text3.php"><span class="font_menue">TEXT 3</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
ul.tabs > li.hasmore::after {
   content: ' | ';
}
```

Check out the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/rLz7b78z/

Answer (score 0):

Just add following css:

```
li:after{
    content: ' | ';
}

li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jztunukL/).

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
ul.tabs > li.hasmore::after {
  content: ' | ';
}

ul.tabs > li.hasmore:last-child::after {
  content: '';
}
```

THX, this works fine :)